# Python - Pandas: difference between monthly mean of day-mean values and monthly mean per se

Tags: python, pandas

I've got different values for mean calculation on a dataframe. Normally, I suppose they should be the same.
Or what's the difference between:

```
daily1 = daily_above_zero['2011-2'].mean()

daily1
Out[181]: 
P_Sanyo_Gesloten    136.751724
P_Sanyo_Open        142.491701
dtype: float64
```

or

```
daily2 = daily_above_zero['2011-2'].resample('m',how='mean')

daily2
Out[187]: 
P_Sanyo_Gesloten    136.751724
P_Sanyo_Open        142.491701
dtype: float64
```

and this:

```
daily2 = daily_above_zero['2011-2'].resample('D',how='mean').mean()

daily2
Out[185]: 
P_Sanyo_Gesloten    132.178545
P_Sanyo_Open        137.536975
dtype: float64
```

Comment: what is daily_above_zero ?

Comment: daily_above_zero is a pandas-dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [11]: df = DataFrame(randn(100000,2),index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=100000,freq='T'),columns=list('AB'))

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 100000 entries, 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-03-11 10:39:00
Freq: T
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    100000  non-null values
B    100000  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2)
```

This is each the sum of all observations per columns / 100000

```
In [13]: df.mean()
Out[13]: 
A   -0.001421
B   -0.000764
dtype: float64
```

This is a mean per column but grouped by month, so differening numbers of obs per month

```
In [14]: df.resample('m',how='mean')
Out[14]: 
                   A         B
2013-01-31 -0.004447  0.003479
2013-02-28  0.001062 -0.002656
2013-03-31  0.000903 -0.008289
```

Just the mean of the above numbers, e.g. the average of the monthly averages

```
In [15]: df.resample('m',how='mean').mean()
Out[15]: 
A   -0.000827
B   -0.002489
dtype: float64
```

Group by each day and then take the mean

```
In [16]: df.resample('D',how='mean')
Out[16]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 70 entries, 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-03-11 00:00:00
Freq: D
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    70  non-null values
B    70  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2)
```

The mean of the mean of the days

```
In [17]: df.resample('D',how='mean').mean()
Out[17]: 
A   -0.001005
B   -0.001491
dtype: float64
```

If for example all of your observations are in the same month, then (you part 1 and part 2 above)

```
df.resample('M',how='mean') == df.mean()
```

Part 3 should be the same, only if, you have a complete set of observations EACH DAY. Not clear in your example if that is the case.

```
In [19]: df['2013-2'].mean()
Out[19]: 
A    0.001062
B   -0.002656
dtype: float64

In [20]: df['2013-2'].resample('D',how='mean').mean()
Out[20]: 
A    0.001062
B   -0.002656
dtype: float64
```

When I mean each day, for my example each day has 60*24 obs

```
In [21]: df['2013-2'].count()
Out[21]: 
A    40320
B    40320
dtype: int64

In [22]: 24*60
Out[22]: 1440
```

28 days in Feb

```
In [23]: 24*60*28
Out[23]: 40320
```